# Google Analytics in Experience Site

Tags: experience-cloud, google-analytics

I implemented Google Analytics in Experience Site, all proper URLs are added to CSP Trusted Sites, although I receive message

> Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=***********' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/ import: blob: https://uip.canary.lwc.dev https://www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js https://www.gstatic.cn". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

How can I solve it?

Edit: Business requirement was to run script only for users who gave us consent to be tracked, so standard solution was inadequate. I added following code to Head Markup:

```
<script>
    const runGoogleAnalytics = function() {
        const w = window;
        const d = document;
        const s = 'script';
        const l = 'dataLayer';
        const i = '***********';
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
            event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s),
            dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    };
    
    const isTrackingConsent = document.cookie.split('; ').some(cookie => {
        const [attr, val] = cookie.split('=');
        return attr.includes('analyticsCookiesConsent') && val === 'true'
    })

    if (isTrackingConsent) {
        runGoogleAnalytics();
    }

    document.addEventListener('rungoogleanalytics', () => {
        runGoogleAnalytics();
    });
```

CSP settings:
[image]

Comment: Did you do exactly this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_g_a_enable.htm&type=5

Comment: No, I did it exactly different :) I edited my question.